# How to pass JSON string with brackets in keys to MVC controller

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have an AJAX call to an MVC controller that is sending a JSON string with left and right square brackets in some of the keys, like this:

```
"Styles": [{
        "Id": 1,
        "Name": "background-color",
        "Value": "#036",
        "Selector": "input[type=text]:hover,input[type=password]:hover"
}]
```

When the controller tries to parse the JSON, it breaks on the brackets:

`The key is invalid JQuery syntax because it is missing a closing bracket.
Parameter name: key`

Is there a way I can send these strings through with the brackets intact or is there a better approach?

**EDIT**:

This fails before it even hits a debugger in my controller. The method that tries to parse it is `System.Web.Mvc.NameValueCollectionValueProvider.NormalizeJQueryToMvc`. Here is what that method is doing:

```
internal static string NormalizeJQueryToMvc(string key)
{
            if (key == null)
            {
                return string.Empty;
            }

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            int i = 0;
            while (true)
            {
                int indexOpen = key.IndexOf('[', i);
                if (indexOpen < 0)
                {
                    sb.Append(key, i, key.Length - i);
                    break; // no more brackets
                }

                sb.Append(key, i, indexOpen - i); // everything up to "["

                // Find closing bracket.
                int indexClose = key.IndexOf(']', indexOpen);
                if (indexClose == -1)
                {
                    throw Error.Argument("key", SRResources.JQuerySyntaxMissingClosingBracket);
                }

                if (indexClose == indexOpen + 1)
                {
                    // Empty bracket. Signifies array. Just remove. 
                }
                else
                {
                    if (char.IsDigit(key[indexOpen + 1]))
                    {
                        // array index. Leave unchanged. 
                        sb.Append(key, indexOpen, indexClose - indexOpen + 1);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // Field name.  Convert to dot notation. 
                        sb.Append('.');
                        sb.Append(key, indexOpen + 1, indexClose - indexOpen - 1);
                    }
                }

                i = indexClose + 1;
                if (i >= key.Length)
                {
                    break; // end of string
                }
            }
            return sb.ToString();
}
```

Comment: This is all perfectly valid JSON. Can you post the code for the controller? There is probably a 'naive' assignment in there that breaks when it finds the internal CSS attribute selector.

Comment: @msanford Great question. I edited my question with the code that's doing the parsing

Comment: Is there a reason you're manually parsing instead of using, say, a JSON parser like JSON.net?

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I was going to ask that, too, until [I found the source](https://forums.asp.net/t/1996064.aspx?jQuery+error+thrown+at+server+side).

Comment: @msanford Ugh. "jQuery format"? "MVC format"? Why? Obligatory: https://xkcd.com/927/

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I, too, found that comical. Still, I'd like to try to help OP if possible.

Comment: Your going to need to send the data as `'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'`, not stringified with `contentType: 'application/json'` which means you need generate the values with indexers - `Styles[0].Id: 1` etc (or write your own `ValueProviderFactory`)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thank you so much! Adding `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"` made it start working right away. If you add this as an answer I'll approve it.